# Material UI TextField event for field leave

Tags: reactjs, events, event-handling, material-ui, textfield

Is there an event for leaving the field or loosing focus in the Material UI TextField?

I need two events, one for entering and one for leaving the field. Entering the field can be handled by using `onFocus`, but is there also one for leaving, i.e. `onFocusLost` or `onUnfocus`? The following code segment show the current use, missing the event for loosing focus.

```
<TextField
    value={this.state.fieldFirstName}
    onChange={(e: any) => this.onChangeFieldFirstName(e.target.value)}
    onFocus={() => this.onFocusFieldFirstName()}
/>
```

Versions in use:

- Node v13.8.0
- npm 6.13.6
- "@material-ui/core": "4.6.1"
- "react": "16.11.0"
- "react-dom": "16.11.0"
- "@types/react": "16.9.11"
- "@types/react-dom": "16.9.4"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
<TextField
value={this.state.fieldFirstName}
onChange={(e: any) => this.onChangeFieldFirstName(e.target.value)}
onFocus={() => this.onFocusFieldFirstName()}
onBlur={() => this.onBlurField()}/>
```

Use onBlur event this will solve your problem

Comment: I am using onBlur but it is called with every onChange

Comment: onBlur work's correctly for me